# Software Updater—what is "Files"?

Tags: updates, update-manager

In the Software Updater, there's an entry called "Files". There's no explanation of what this is or what purpose it serves.

Does anyone know what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Files" is the user-oriented name for the package Nautilus. Or to be precise: for whatever your default file browser is. You could change it to e.g. Nemo.